# Why is $\frac{x}{\| x \|}$ a unit vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Let $x$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Why is $\frac{x}{\| x \|}$ a unit vector, for $x\neq 0$?

If I try to simplify it, I get the following: $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x \cdot x}}$, and I'm not sure how to proceed.

So I'm looking for a proof or explanation as to why it is a unit vector.

Comment: What happens when you try finding its norm?

Comment: More generally, if $\lambda>0$ is a real number, what is $\|\lambda x\|$?

Comment: Let $u=\frac{x}{||x||}$. Try to find $u.u$ and deduce $||u||=\sqrt{u.u}$.

Comment: I am sure that this question is a duplicate, but I couldn't find its doppelgänger.

Comment: @user1551 I also could swear this question has been asked in the past two weeks, and received nearly identical answers. Perhaps I am from two weeks in the future!

Comment: @rschwieb I have a vague impression that this question has been asked lately too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Show that for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we have
$$\|\lambda x\|=|\lambda|\cdot\|x\|.$$
What does this become when $x\neq 0$ and $\lambda=\frac{1}{\|x\|}$?

Comment: Thank you. Makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 5):

Apply the norm $\|\cdot\|$ to this vector. You get $\left\| \frac  x {\|x\|} \right\|$. By one of the properties of a norm this is the same as $\frac 1 {\|x\|} \|x\| = 1.$

Comment: @SujaanKunalan: Of course my answer assumed that you had already shown that $\sqrt{x\cdot x}$ satisfies all the axioms of a norm, so Zev's answer was probably more helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

First, we have
$$
\langle x,x\rangle=\|x\|^2
$$
Since the inner product is bilinear, we get
$$
\left\langle\frac{x}{\|x\|},\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\rangle=\frac{\|x\|^2}{\|x\|\,\|x\|}
$$

Comment: I'm not familiar with inner product. Is it something along the lines of squaring the dot product?

Comment: @SujaanKunalan "Inner product" is sometimes used synonymously with "dot product."